# Graphs with bounded degree: how many are there?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Can one count the number of undirected (simple) graphs on $n$ nodes with degree at most $d$? Asymptotic bounds would be helpful too.

Comment: Are the nodes labeled (i.e. distinguishable) ?